# Android Connection with Oracle Database

Tags: java, android, sql, oracle, connection

by clicking a button, i want to execute a select query to show some results,i used the Internet permission and the AsyncTask and the address ip of my PC to perform this call but it didn t work for me,Also the Log doesn't show me Anything to figure out the issue,this is the code:

in Manifest file:

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Android programm:

```
package com.ammach.oraclecon;  
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    class Task extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

            String param="mal9a walou";
            String driver="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
            String bd="ORCL";
            String user="SYSTEM";
            String passwd="SYSTEM";
            String port="1521";
            String ip="192.168.1.7";
            String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@"+ip+":"+port+":"+bd;

            Connection con=null;
                try {
                    Class.forName(driver);
                    con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
                    Log.e("coooon", "coooon");
                    Statement st=con.createStatement();
                    Log.e("Statement", "Statement");
                    ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("select * from auteur");
                    Log.e("ResultSet", "ResultSet");

                    Log.e("con", "You made it, take control your database now!");
                    if(resultSet.next()){
                        param=resultSet.getString("nom");
                        Log.e("dkhal", "rah dkhal");
                    }else{
                        Log.e("walou", "walou");
                    }

                } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            return param;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String param) {
            super.onPostExecute(param);
            textView.setText(param);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "finished", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    TextView textView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    }

    public void fetchOracle(View view) {

        new Task().execute();
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

i Also run the same procedure in a simple java project(void main) in Netbeans, and it works perfectly,i tried so many times the Android application but i failed ,could someone help me to solve this issue.

this is the java programm:

```
        String param = "nothing";
        String driver = "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver";
        String bd = "ORCL";
        String user = "SYSTEM";
        String passwd = "SYSTEM";
        String port = "1521";
        String ip = "localhost";
        String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@" + ip + ":" + port + ":" + bd;

        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName(driver);
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, passwd);
            Statement st = con.createStatement();
            ResultSet resultSet = st.executeQuery("select * from auteur");
            if (resultSet.next()) {
                param = resultSet.getString("nom");

            } else {
                System.out.println("no result");
            }
            System.out.println("nom: "+param);
        } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: are you on a real android device or the emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your catch clause with the only statement e.printStackTrace(); makes the trick. It just swallows the exception and you, of course, unable to see it. It is much better to use the Log class to report the caught exception. Insert there something like Log.e("tag", e.toString()); and you'll see the problem.

Next you should always close all the resources you have used. In your case it's the Connection, the Statement and the ResultSet. The correct place to close them is in your (missed) finally clause.

But anyway, if you want to work with Oracle from Android device then you should ensure the network 192.168.1.* is reachable from your device and the address (192.168.1.7) at least can be pinged successfully (from your device). Have you managed to somehow test the connection? And there can be much more reasons to get an exception (which is silently swallowed in your code), it means the first thing you should do is to change your code and to log exception properly. Next it can be a missing JDBC driver library, it can be a network configuration problem which makes the database unreachable (most probable), it can be the problem on the side of the Oracle if you have no permission to read from "auteur", etc.

Comment: i pinged my PC from my phone and it s reachable, i changed the code with the the remarks u mentionned, and it gives me the exception below:

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: Exception d'E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection

Comment: the problem is that the url is working in simple project in netbeans

Comment: **bold** The Network Adapter could not establish the connection **bold**

Comment: You should check the connection. Even if your PC is reachable there still could be many problems. For example - your firewall denies acces to the port 1521 or something else.

Comment: finally i solved the problem by openning the port and importing the suitable jar ojdbc6 instead of ojdbc14